# PHP Regex: remove div with class "image"

Tags: php, regex, replace, match

I need to remove all images in a variable using the following pattern. (With PHP).

```
<div class="float-right image"> 
  <img class="right" src="http://www.domain.com/media/images/image001.png" alt="">
</div>
```

All the div tags will have an **image** class, but the float-right might vary. I can't seem to get the regex working, please help me.

Comment: Have you tried using an HTML parser instead? Read this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/robust-mature-html-parser-for-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex matches your pattern:

```
(?s)<div class="[^"]*">\W*<img\W*class="[^"]*"\W*src="[^"]*"\W*alt="[^"]*">\W*</div>
```

I have tested it against several strings. It will work on:

```
<div class="anything"> 
<img class="blah" src="anything" alt="blah">
</div>
```

, where you can replace the "blah" and "anything" strings with anything.
Also, the various \W* in the regex allow for different spacing from string to string.

You said you want to do this in PHP.

This will zap all the matched patterns from a page stored in the $my_html variable.

```
$my_html=preg_replace('%(?s)<div class="[^"]*">\W*<img\W*class="[^"]*"\W*src="[^"]*"\W*alt="[^"]*">\W*</div>%m', '', $my_html);
```

I think this is what you were looking for?

Comment: Yes, that is my solution. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3):

Use a DOM instead of regex. Example:

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML('<div class="float-right image"> 
  <img class="right" src="http://www.domain.com/media/images/image001.png" alt="">
</div>');

foreach( $doc->getElementsByTagName("div") as $old_img ) {
    $img = $doc->createElement("img");
    $src = $doc->createAttribute('src');
    $class = $doc->createAttribute('class');
    $src->value = 'http://your.new.link';
    $class->value = 'right';
    $img->appendChild($src);
    $img->appendChild($class);
    $doc->replaceChild($img, $old_img);
}

echo $doc->saveHTML();
?>
```

Comment: Hey, I did try it, but it seems to not work on the server somehow. But basically, all I need is to find a div with the class "image" and possible other classes, but they do not matter. Than I just want to remove the whole div from the string. How can I do this with regex?

Comment: I don't know regex even though I tried many times to learn it, so I'm trying to avoid it.